# How to linearize the following objective function?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am new to this forum. 
I need to solve a problem by optimizing it.
I would like to know if there is a way to linearize or to obtain a quadratic function from the following objective function.

min $\beta + \frac{\gamma}{x} + x\delta $

s.t. $x \geq 1$

$x \in N$

The only decision variable is $x$.
The original idea that I had was to multiply everything for $x$. That would lead to the following equation

min $x\beta + \gamma + x^2\delta $

which does not have the same derivative of the previous one and therefore it does not lead to the same solution.
Or maybe I did something wrong in the process?
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Which are the decision variables?

Comment: x is an integer? If so you must know that in general best integer solution is not the one resulting from rounding the best real solution